# How can I find all untagged questions on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, untagged-questions

I know how the [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) tag works, but under (clicking on) the [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) tag on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged), we don't get all questions tagged with [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged).

For example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686216/what-code-would-you-have-on-your-wedding-cake) question tagged with [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged), but it isn't there in the [untagged questions list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged).

I tried the new search engine and also `https://stackoverflow.com/search`, but I still can't find all those questions. Is there a way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned, [locked questions are not listed in tag pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183458/187824).

But locked questions can be searched through the [search page](https://stackoverflow.com/search). So in the search page/search box try this keyword:

```
[untagged] is:q
```

[Result](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Buntagged%5D%20is:q)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that locked questions won't show up on the list, which is pretty silly since that question has the official 'historical significance' stamp.

It can be found by direct search with `[untagged] cake`, so it will show up in some search results, just not by searching on the tag itself.

Comment: Hmm, so if we try to find locked and tagged with untagged questions, we can't find them with searching, right?

Comment: @Soner, there is no way currently to specifically search locked questions.