# Why the untagged tagged questions not visible?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, untagged-questions

I know that we have the [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) tag in Stack Overflow. I can see that there are 4 questions tagged with that tag.

[image: an image of the "untagged" tag blurb with "4" shown for the number of questions with that tag]

But, when I click on that tag, I can't see those questions. I clicked on all (Newest, Unanswered, Active, Votes) tabs.

What is the reason for that?

Comment: I found questions tagged with [`[untagged]`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Buntagged%5D+is%3Aq) from the search page.

Comment: Caching. The answer is always caching

Comment: @AakashM - No. [No at all](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164342/187824)

Comment: @hims056, yes you can find those 4 questions by anyother possible ways, but my question is why it does not showing on directly clicking on that tag?

Comment: That question is asked for a way to find those questions, here I asked the reason for not showing them, I think there is some difference between them.

Comment: The answer is still given in the other question; all 4 `[untagged]` questions are locked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All 4 questions tagged with [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) are locked for historical significance. Historically-locked questions are not listed on tag pages.

From [What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for/126631#126631):

> Historically-locked questions are omitted from normal question lists (those on the home page, /questions, and the various per-tag lists), but can still be found by searching for words in the post or title (via either site-search or Google, etc).