# 'Possible duplicate' comment not appearing for questions with deleted comments containing the link

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, deleted-comments, automatic-comments

I posted a comment to a duplicate question on [that post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183453/why-the-untagged-tagged-questions-not-visible). But I decided to delete it. Afterwards I voted as duplicate and thought a comment would be generated like

> possible duplicate of ...

But it didn't. My guess is that the duplicate-comment won't be generated if a comment exists with that link, **even if deleted**.

Comment: Yeh. I also closed that question but it didn't add a comment on behalf of me. (As I didn't add/delete comment regarding duplicate)

Comment: Was there a different "possible duplicate of.." comment already, when you tried adding yours?

Comment: @alldani: I don't know. That was 3.5 years ago. But I think not.

Comment: Thanks. Just curious. Because I had something like this happen to me, but there _was_ another comment already. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288946/voting-to-close-as-a-second-dupe-didnt-add-a-second-comment