# If the link has been posted (say as a related link), the possible duplicate comment doesn't appear

Tags: discussion, comments, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, automatic-comments

These comments essentially explain it: (can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251809/please-can-we-have-all-the-logos))

> [image]

Roombatron5000 added a related link. Then Shadow Wizard voted to close as a duplicate, but because the link has been given, the "possible duplicate" auto comment wasn't added.

I assume this is because the system doesn't allow multiple "possible duplicate" comments - one for each close vote. However, is there some way that it could look for the comment ID (or similar), rather than looking for a comment with the link in?

This matters less to the OP - as they see the "possible duplicate" banner, but other users may have missed it and not close voted it as well.

Related, possible duplicates: [“possible duplicate” comment should be re-added if it's been deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93893/possible-duplicate-comment-should-be-re-added-if-its-been-deleted) and ['Possible duplicate' comment not appearing for questions with deleted comments containing the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183455/possible-duplicate-comment-not-appearing-for-questions-with-deleted-comments-c), but this is talking about it not appearing because of a different comment, not a possible duplicate comment.

Comment: And, as consequence, another link gets nuked when the question is closed. That's annoying.

Comment: Did you test? I know that earlier I commented on a question with a link to another question. Then the question was closed and my link was immediately nuked. This bug is related to yours.

Comment: That question was closed my shadow and then me (community) so evidently that doesn't happen...